# What is easiest to maintain when implementing different functionality for each subclass? Downcasting, Reflection or Polymorphism?

Tags: architecture, polymorphism, type-casting

I'm interested in knowing what is a good way to architect a system that can act differently based on the subclass being passed in. I assume polymorphism is the least computationally intensive.

I'm going to paste some short, functional code. The `Program` class is the same for both snippets. I deliberately left out Interfaces and dumb-ified the code to so as to be as short as possible.

The code is of a game where the player has to make Choices. Each `Choice` can have different `Outcomes`, which are chosen based on some logic, which I randomized in the Program, as to illustrate that this is outside the system.

Also, the `Choice` does not have the right to implement its `Outcome`, only the `OutcomeExecutioner` has, which means that the `Choice` is very much a data container for an `Outcome`, which is itself a data container for what has to happen.

My top-pick for now is using the `template method` pattern because the OutcomeExecutioner doesn't have to do any casting/reflecting. It just calls a function. Then again, it does use memory space for an extra member, which is just a reference so probably not a big deal? It's also cleaner and allows for creating an `interface` so that in the future the `OutcomeExecutioner` could be replaced with a different Executioner.

```
class Choice
{
    public OutcomeBase Outcome;

    public Choice (OutcomeBase outcome)
    {
        this.Outcome = outcome;
    }

}

abstract class OutcomeBase
{
    public OutcomeExecutioner Executioner;

    abstract public void TriggerOutcome();
}

class OutcomeMove : OutcomeBase
{
    override public void TriggerOutcome()
    {
        Executioner.TriggerMove(this);
    }
}

class OutcomeTalk : OutcomeBase
{
    override public void TriggerOutcome()
    {
        Executioner.TriggerTalk(this);
    }
}

class OutcomeExecutioner
{
    public void OnChoice(Choice choice)
    {
        choice.Outcome.Executioner = this;
        choice.Outcome.TriggerOutcome();
    }

    public void TriggerMove(OutcomeMove move)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Move");
    }

    public void TriggerTalk(OutcomeTalk talk)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Talk");
    }

}
```

And this is using downcasting. The same goes for reflection, except that instead of using a cast based on `OutcomeType`, I can simply use reflection and remove that `OutcomeType` enum alltogether (although Reflection might be more computationally intensive, and I do work with a **huge** data set, so probably I'd leave the enum in).

```
enum OutcomeType
{
    Move,
    Talk
}

class Choice
{
    public OutcomeBase outcome;

    public Choice(OutcomeBase outcome)
    {
        this.outcome = outcome;
    }

}

abstract class OutcomeBase
{
    public OutcomeType OType;
}

class OutcomeMove : OutcomeBase
{
    public OutcomeMove()
    {
        OType = OutcomeType.Move;
    }
}

class OutcomeTalk : OutcomeBase
{
    public OutcomeTalk()
    {
        OType = OutcomeType.Talk;
    }
}

class OutcomeExecutioner
{
    public void OnChoice(Choice choice)
    {
        switch (choice.outcome.OType)
        {
            case OutcomeType.Move:
                TriggerMove((OutcomeMove)choice.outcome);
                break;
            case OutcomeType.Talk:
                TriggerTalk((OutcomeTalk)choice.outcome);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void TriggerMove(OutcomeMove move)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Move");
    }

    public void TriggerTalk(OutcomeTalk talk)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Talk");
    }
}
```

Comment: Read [Wizards and Warriors](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: "I assume polymorphism is the least computationally intensive" - this is probably not a concern in in most cases (but reflection the worst in this respect). If you have radically different subclasses, then don't force them into a hierarchy at all. If there is a common interface/abstraction, and it's expressive enough and you expect it to change rarely, then go with subclasses, especially if you can smoothly add new features by writing a new subclass. If you really have a fixed number of subclasses, but need to add new methods, do downcasts or pattern matching within those methods.

Comment: (You dindn't specify a language, but looks like C# - by pattern matching I mean [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching))

Comment: Also why reinvent what is essentially a function? `TriggerOutcome()` could simply be a property of type `Action` (A function wrapper for non C# users), perhaps `Action<Argument>` if you want to pass context to the outcome. Now instead of having everything implemented in executioner, the logic can be implemented wherever it makes sense but called as the `outcome` of a `choice`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey that was a brilliant read. I need to re-read it about 3-4 times, and then also code along, that's how good it is. It also acted as a sort of good omen for certain other things I'm doing with my code. Excellent :).

Comment: @FilipMilovanović haha, I actually was stumbling around trying to do something like pattern matching in the older C# version I'm using :D. Thing with pattern matching is that it's still reflection, isn't it? (uses "is").

Comment: @Kain0_0 That's a useful idea. Although in my use case, the Executioner is the only place where this logic can reside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be focusing too much on premature micro-optimizations. Unless you are on a really tight memory or computing time budget (less than 1MB total memory, or you need the frame-rate of a video game) an extra virtual member or a virtual function call are not going to make a significant impact.

What *is* making an impact is how easy your code will be to understand for new maintainers (including yourself in 6 months) and how easy it is to add new Choices/Outcomes.

As an example, lets try to add an `OutcomeTurn` in both solutions:

In the inheritance case, there are two changes (additions) to make

1. Add a new method `TriggerTurn(OutcomeTurn)` to `OutcomeExecutioner`.
2. Add a new subclass `OutcomeTurn` that derives from `OutcomeBase`.

Most importantly, the code for invoking an outcome is not affected at all and if you forget one of the changes, code trying to use the new outcome will fail to build.

---

In the casting/reflection case, there are 4 (or 3) changes to make

1. Add a new method `TriggerTurn(OutcomeTurn)` to `OutcomeExecutioner`.
2. Add a new subclass `OutcomeTurn` that derives from `OutcomeBase`.
3. Add a new enumerator value to `OutcomeType`
4. Extend the switch in `OutcomeExecutioner::OnChoice` to handle calling the new outcome.

If you miss that last change, at best you might get a warning that not all enumerator values are covered by the switch statement. At worst, you will notice at run-time that the selected choice has no noticeable effect. Those dispatch functions are also usually not covered that well by unittests, as it is easy to forget you might need to add one and the logic appears simple enough that it can be verified by reviews only.

Comment: Good way to solve the dilemma. It also happens to be less computationally intensive since it's not reflection. As for use case, it's not exactly frame rates but rather concurrent users going through massive troves of data that concerns me. Fortunately, such things can be scaled pretty well. As long as the initial architecture is sound :). I was also looking to see if there's anything really wrong with doing any of these :) (or if there is a whole new way that I have not considered). I need to better digest the "Wizards and Warriors" link posted by Robert in the comments to my OP.